# Dropdown selection value in textbox from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

here's the code dropdown and textbox:

```
<form id="myForm">
<label for="departmentsDropdown"><b>Department</b></label>
<select class="form-control" onchange="getValue()"
        id="numero_control" name="numero_control">
</select><br />
<input type="text" value="" id="Nombre" /><br>
<input type="text" value="" id="id" /><br>
</form>
```

function onchange:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

     <div class="jumbotron">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetData",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                var s = '<option value="-1">Porfavor selecciona algun valor</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    s += '<option value="' + data[i].Nombre + data[i].id + '">' + 
            data[i].numero_control + '</option>';
                   
                }
                $("#numero_control").html(s);

            }
        });
    });

    function getValue() {
        var myVal = $("#numero_control").val();
        $("#Nombre").val(myVal);
        $("#id").val(myVal);

       }
   </script>
 </div>
```

Controller action method:

```
crudEntities db = new crudEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = from als in
    db.registro select new 
     { als.id, als.Nombre,als.numero_control };
        
        return Json(data.ToList(),
      JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

my error is I have two value in the dropdown i was load in two textbox the problem is if i run the project watch the two value in one textbox input:

Image of the error:
[image: error]

I would like it to come out like this:
I have information such as id, Nombre, numero_control. When I choose the numero_control from the dropdown, I want to print id on one of the 2 textboxes and id on the other textbox.

I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2CYzFkeQ_M) to do it.